# Chrome History API problems

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, browser-history

I'm having problems with a website is Chrome.

Most of the site uses ajax/xmlhttprequest for pages loads and the history API to enable the back button. Only the page content is changing with the request, the menu etc are never reloaded. This just re-reuns the ajax request for the previous page. This all works fine until someone clicks the back button after viewing the blog. The blog isn't loaded with ajax, it's just a standard link.

In Firefox if I go to the blog then press back the site loads correctly. The main page with the navigation loaded and so is the page to be viewed within it.

In Chrome however if I press the back button from the blog the 'outer' page isn't loaded, only the contents of the ajax request is. You may need to view it to fully understand.

Is this a bug in Chrome or my work? It seems I can't return to a page that was partially loaded using xmlhttprequest as only the requested item is loaded.

The site is here: http://www.basmooarc.com

Thanks

Ric

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### short answer

Add a `Cache-Control: no-store` HTTP header for XHR responses.

### long answer

I'm pretty sure this is a bug in Chrome. I found the exact same bug in my app, and it works fine in Firefox but breaks in Chrome. I think the issue is that Chrome caches the XHR response and serves it from the cache when you press the back button. My app uses Etags, but Chrome does not bother to check the Etag. It just uses the cached response, which is missing all the outer content. The best solution I've come up with so far is to add `no-store` to the cache control header for XHR responses.

You can see the behavior through Chrome's net-internals page. Type `chrome://net-internals` in the URL bar, open the Events tab and go through the steps to reproduce your bug. When you go to a non-ajax page and then press the back button, you'll see a URL_REQUEST entry for the URL of the page you're trying to go to, but Chrome just checks the cache and that's it. Contrast that with a normal request for that URL. The normal one will have a cache check, followed by an HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST section, which is where Chrome makes the actual HTTP request.